# Jenkins not connecting on 8080 port on AWS EC2 Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04

I've installed GitLab and Jenkins on AWS EC2 Ubuntu 18.04, where GitLab uses 80, while Jenkins uses 8080. Gitlab work OK, has external access, while Jenkins doesn't.

```
sudo systemctl status jenkins
```

shows that Jenkins is up and running, also curl get's login page, but I can't access it from my browser from external machine.

```
http://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/
```

I am using same URL but with port 80 for GitLab.

Firewall on both AWS and server are open. Any advice what else could be wrong?

Comment: Did you confirm Jenkins is running on port 8080 ?

Comment: Yes, it is running on port 8080

Comment: Configure security group of ec2 instance to incoming traffic to 8080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that host name was wrong.
I set it with:

```
sudo hostnamectl set-hostname ip-XX-XX-XX-XX
```

Then rebooted server, and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same problem and solved the issue by:

1 )  `vim /etc/sysconfig/jenkins` .

2 )  Change: `JENKINS_LISTEN_ADDRESS` from `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you set the custom TCP inbound rule for port 8080 in the security group.

```
IPv4    Custom TCP  TCP 8080
```